# Moved Android Studio project folder. All files are now red, but project works

Tags: android-studio

I recently moved my project by a simple cut/paste to a parent folder. Now, all my files are red but the project still works fine.

See red files here

[image]

I have attempted to invalidate caches/restart and rebuild the project. What is this red color indicating and how do I fix this?

Comment: This red color indicates that changes have not been saved in the version manager as git ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color red on files does not represent any error. It simply indicates that your files are not added to the version control(i.e. git/bitbucket etc.). The color will get change when you update files to the version control.